# How to find RowID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I use `Row_Number()`, then I need to use `order by` or `partition by`. That will not solve my issue here:

Tab_1 (input table)

[image]

Expected output (running total)

[image]

In this case, if I write a query

```
Select name, sum(Sal) over(order by name)
from tab_1
```

it will not return perfect result as name is in order by.

Comment: So which column do you want to use to order the cumulative sum?

Comment: Correct - but you seem to be under the misplaced assumption that rows in a table have a defined order that you can use for things such as this. Either you add a column for this purpose or you cannot accomplish your goal.

Comment: I want the output table.. how to get it @GMB

Comment: Rows in the table do not have and order, if you wish to keep order from Tab_1 printout then you need to add a column to this table defining order,

Answer (score 2):

To respect the order that the data was inserted you need something extra in the table.
For example an ID that's automatically filled by an IDENTITY.
Then you can use that extra field in the sorting.

**For example:**

```
-- using a table variable as demonstration
declare @tab_1 table (
 Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 Sal DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

insert into @tab_1 (Name, Sal) values
('A',100),
('C',200),
('D',150),
('B',50);

SELECT
 Name,
 SUM(Sal) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS CumulativeSalary,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowId
FROM @tab_1
ORDER BY Id;
```

**Returns:**

```
Name    CumulativeSalary    RowId
A       100,00              1
C       300,00              2
D       450,00              3
B       500,00              4
```

Without some column to sort on?
Perhaps the hidden virtual columns `%%LockRes%%` or `%%physloc%%` could be used.

For example with this test table (without PK):

```
CREATE TABLE tab_1 (
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 Sal DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
INSERT INTO tab_1 (Name, Sal) VALUES
('A',100),
('C',200),
('D',150),
('B',50);
```

A query that uses `%%LockRes%%`:

```
SELECT
 Name,
 SUM(Sal) OVER (ORDER BY n1, n2, n3) AS CumulativeSalary,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n1, n2, n3) AS RowId
FROM tab_1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE( %%LockRes%%, ':','.'),3) AS INT) AS n1,
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE( %%LockRes%%, ':','.'),2) AS INT) AS n2,
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE( %%LockRes%%, ':','.'),1) AS INT) AS n3
) o
ORDER BY RowId;
```

Or one that uses `%%physloc%%`:

```
SELECT
 Name,
 SUM(Sal) OVER (ORDER BY %%physloc%%) AS CumulativeSalary,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY %%physloc%%) AS RowId
FROM tab_1
ORDER BY RowId;
```

Both return the same result.

Comment: Well, I found [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-know-the-insertion-order-of-records-in-a-table) related article. But not sure how much one can depend on such special unsupported tricks.  Using an ID or some DatetimeCreated field would be more dependable.

Comment: @AryanSena Just for amusement I've added some alternatives.  But unsure how dependable they are with a big table.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select name, 
sum(Sal) Sal, 
row_number() over(order by sum(Sal)) Row_id 
from tab_1 group by name
```

Comment: the query is not giving proper result.

Answer (score 1):

A running total requires a *row order* to compute it's result. The engine's "default" order has no meaning and it's likely to change over time depending on the table's pages allocation and indexes. Consistent row order by repeating the same `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` ***is not guaranteed*** on SQL Server.

It's easy to think that with an example of a testing table with just 4 rows, executing the same `SELECT` over and over again and seeing the same result will make you think that there's an implicit order, it's likely that the engine just returning the rows as they were stored as a heap. If you create a clustering index, it will probably change. In any case, you should never assume any order as it would make an awful programming practice.

So as long as you don't have a particular column to correctly arrange the rows, **your current problem has no solution**. I'd recommend always adding a datetime column with a default value (for example: `CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()`) so at least you know when each row was created and can order by that (although it's possible that the inserting process explicitly denotes `NULL` on this column, which would be nerve-racking).

Comment: Thanks :).. but in oracle it is possible right as Oracle has RowId.

Comment: Oracle has a `RowID` but it seems that it's also not guaranteed to be consistently matching against the row insertion order. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73884/oracle-rowid-can-we-assume-it-is-sequential-in-a-insert-only-scenario

Answer (score 1):

create table #Table(Name char(1),Salary int)

insert into #Table
select 'A',100
insert into #Table
select 'C',200
insert into #Table
select 'D',150
insert into #Table
select 'B',50

;with cte as(
SELECT *
      ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select (1000)))
FROM #Table
) select Name,CumulativeSum = Sum(salary) over (order by RN),RN from cte

i think i found the solution.